# php URL decode get '+' from URL

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

So I am trying to encode/decode a url that when decoded will return the encoded `+` symbols from teh url. For example, I encode`website.com/index.php?eq=1+12` which when encoded turns the `+` into `%2B`, as it should. When I retrieve the value from `$_REQUEST['eq']` and use `urldecode()` it echo's as `"1 12"`. I cannot seem to get the decode to bring back the `+` so to speak. Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a more efficient/better way to go about doing this? Here is the exact encode/decode lines I use.

Submit Page

```
<?php
$eq = "1+12";
$send = '<a href="website.com/index.php?eq='.urlencode($eq).'</a>';
echo $send;
```

Retrieval page

```
<?php
$eq = urldecode($_REQUEST['eq']);
echo $eq;
?>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't run `urldecode`, the data in `$_REQUEST` is automatically decoded for you.

A plus sign, in a URL, is an encoded space. PHP decodes the hex value to a `+` automatically. Then, by running the result through `urldecode`, you are manually (and incorrectly) decoding the `+` to a .

Comment: so I removed the urldecode, and kept the urlencode. It still is registering the $_REQUEST as a space.

Comment: It doesn't when I copy/paste that code and remove the `urldecode` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe the php version is different and functions differently? Or could be other parts of my page conflicting. I figured a workaround by using str_replace(" ", "+", $eq). Probably not ideal, but since my URL will never need spaces, seems to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It probably is some other part of your code. You should trace through and find out what modifies it and where (starting with checking that the URL in the link is actually containing `eq=1%2B12`.

Comment: @Andrew — That is what the line "urldecode($_REQUEST['eq'])" in the question does. It is the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Try using the function `rawurldecode()`  instead of `urldecode()`

Comment: yes, it't the solution

Answer (score 2):

I encode it in JavaScript with `encodeURIComponent()` and decode it in PHP with `rawurldecode()` and it encodes/decodes properly for me, including the "+", but **NOT** with `urldecode()`